# CriteriaBuilder EmbeddedId Joins

Tags: java, jpa, join

I'm still new to Java but I'm having problems with an application framework when I turn off Solr (To see changes made to database) I get an error because one of the classes is still using using an attribute that no longer exists.

Part 1: I have no idea why this was changed, and doesn't use a ManyToMany anymore, most likely a workaround for some limitation I guess.

```
public class CategoryImpl implements Category, Status, AdminMainEntity {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = CategoryProductXrefImpl.class, mappedBy = "categoryProductXref.category")
    protected List<CategoryProductXref> allProductXrefs = new ArrayList<CategoryProductXref>(10);
```

Part 2:

```
public class CategoryProductXrefImpl implements CategoryProductXref {

    @EmbeddedId
    CategoryProductXrefPK categoryProductXref = new CategoryProductXrefPK();

    public CategoryProductXrefPK getCategoryProductXref() {
        return categoryProductXref;
    }

    public void setCategoryProductXref(CategoryProductXrefPK categoryProductXref) {
        this.categoryProductXref = categoryProductXref;
    }

    public void setCategoryProductXref(CategoryProductXrefPK categoryProductXref) {
        this.categoryProductXref = categoryProductXref;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return categoryProductXref.getCategory();
    }


    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        categoryProductXref.setCategory(category);
    }


    public Product getProduct() {
        return categoryProductXref.getProduct();
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        categoryProductXref.setProduct(product);
    }
```

Part 3:

```
@Embeddable
public class CategoryProductXrefPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = CategoryImpl.class, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    protected Category category = new CategoryImpl();

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProductImpl.class, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    protected Product product = new ProductImpl();
```

Problem was in ProductDao

```
public List<Product> readFilteredActiveProductsByCategory(Long categoryId, Date currentDate, 
        ProductSearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    // Set up the criteria query that specifies we want to return Products
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Product> criteria = builder.createQuery(Product.class);

    // The root of our search is Category since we are browsing
    Root<CategoryImpl> category = criteria.from(CategoryImpl.class);

    // We want to filter on attributes from product and sku
    Join<Category, Product> product = category.join("allProducts"); <--Problem Occurs Here
    Join<Product, Sku> sku = product.join("defaultSku");

    // Product objects are what we want back
    criteria.select(product);
```

I've tried this:

```
    Join<CategoryImpl, CategoryProductXrefImpl> catXref = category.join("allProductXrefs");
    Join<CategoryProductXrefImpl, Product> product = catXref.join("product");
    Join<Product, Sku> sku = product.join("defaultSku");
```

I've tried it by Implementation, tried with  a third join like:

```
Join<CategoryProductXrefImpl, CategoryProductXrefPK>,
```

tried using CategoryProductXrefPK instead of XrefImpl, Tried using CategoryProductXref as a second Root. I've spent a few days on this searching and trying different things. I ran out of ideas.

Comment: JPA does not allow relationships within an embeddedId.  The keys from Category and Product make up CategoryProductXrefImpl's id, not the entities themselves.  The mappedby should just point to a category mapping directly on CategoryProductXrefImpl, with the CategoryProductXrefPK embeddedId using the same basic keys from Category and Product.  The category mapping on CategoryProductXrefImpl would then use the @MapsId annotation to point to the field within the embeddabled ID.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html for an example

Comment: Hey Chris... you pointed out the only direction that is suitable for this issue, and this is the only answer on the internet available in this topic. I owe you, man. You saved my day ;)